# overriding css not working anymore

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hi there guys last night I was working on a bootstrap template and i tried to override the global css file and add a style to the main page as .body to override the global css file and added a background image ; when i added it changed as i wanted and worked pretty fine but then today when i tried to run the same template again it references back to the global css and totally ignores the styles section in the main page.i also added some new fonts to it but now they are not working too.

**Code from my preferred style**

```
.page {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        transition: width 0.3s linear;
        width: calc(100% - 200px);
        background-image: url("../../assets/images/main2.jpg") !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 50% 0;
        background-size: cover;

        min-height: 100vh;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
    }
```

**Code from global css**

```
.page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: width 0.3s linear;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background-color: #292b2c ;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
          }
```

here is also the template with the changes i added to it:
http://hifitapp.ir/test

Comment: Check once background-image url.

Comment: The location of the background image is wrong. You have `"../../assets/images/main2.jpg"` but the image is located at `"/test/assets/images/main2.jpg"`.

Comment: the reason I'm using the ../../assets/images/main2.jpg is that I am using a php framework so the routing is a bit different.but it is fine, i mean last night it was working flawlessly with the same links. you can inspect the elements and see the css components .it is already loading them when you inspect them but still referencing  to external css file.

Comment: And a font file name like "  .ttf" looks iffy too.

Comment: u can inspect  <div class="page home-page"> it will show the css components

Comment: @faramarz Yes, and it tries to load http://hifitapp.ir/assets/images/main2.jpg which doesn't exist, because the graphic is located elsewhere, as the comments above say.

Comment: yes, it seems i had to give an online url but could you help me with the fonts ? should i reference to online fonts?